# Wordpress popular tags mechanism

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

This is a general concept question, how does wordpress calculate the popular tags? I have tried to experiment with get_tags

```
$tags = get_tags(array(
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'orderby' => 'count',
  'number' => 10,
  'pad_counts' => true,
  'hide_empty' => true
));
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo '$tag->count';
}
```

I tried to repeated visit a page with certain tag, but it doesn't tell me how popular the tag is. How would I know if a tag is popular or not? I would like to find out which variable or parameter is responsible for the tag popularity. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_tag_cloud` and `orderby` => `count` so it will return most popular tag first then other popular as so on.

It will show tags by its usage in posts by count.

```
$tags = wp_tag_cloud(array(
    'echo' => false,
    'orderby' => 'count',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo '$tag->count';
}
```

Comment: thanks, but orderby count is counting the number of times the tag is being used, rather than number of times the tag is being queried or visited, so it does not reflect the popularity as in most viewed tags.

Comment: yes so how you are using most popular?most viewed tag?

Comment: yes, I think the most popular should be the most viewed

Comment: so that it truly reflects what tags are frequently visited, thus the popularity

Comment: how are you counting post views?

Comment: I'm looking into using post_meta_data as a key, and use a hook in a post to update the count as the post_meta_value, but I'm still experimenting, ultimately I want to count the most visited tags then display it to the users

Comment: please refer to this link for more details of post view count : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269105/orderby-post-views